# Thread safety of a Servlet's Toolbox shared method

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am fairly new to threads and I've been reading lots of Q/A on stack overflow for about a week now.
I have a question that i can not find a definite answer to it. I hope you can help me. Here is a sample code:

```
public class servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HashMap<String,String> map = null;
        ... // add some entries to the hash map 
        ArrayList<String> info = Toolbox.extractInformation(map);
        // 1. use the info to generate the response to the client
        // 2. Send response to the client
        // <End>
    }
}

public class servlet2 extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HashMap<String,String> map = null;
        ... // add some entries to the hash map 
        ArrayList<String> info = Toolbox.extractInformation(map);
        // 1. use the info to generate the response to the client
        // 2. Send response to the client
        // <End>            
    }
}

public class Toolbox {
public static ArrayList<String> extractInformation(HashMap<String,String> map) {
    ...
    }
}
```

In the current scenario I have 2 (or more) Servlets in which are both using a common Toolbox method without any synchronization.
As far as i understand this should be thread safe because each thread will create a copy of the method and method arguments in it's own stack and execute independently.
The Toolbox method uses no instance variables, only the passed arguments. It manipulates the arguments and return another object, in this case an ArrayList
Knowing that the container might execute multiple threads on the same servlet instance

My question is:

- Is Toolbox.extractInformation(...) considered thread safe?

Your help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct is correct - there are indeed opportunities for thread-based issues here:

```
    HashMap<String,String> map = null;
    ... // add some entries to the hash map 
    ArrayList<String> info = Toolbox.extractInformation(map);
```

If you meant:

```
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    ... // add some entries to the hash map 
    ArrayList<String> info = Toolbox.extractInformation(map);
```

in which case so long as you don't add the **same object** to the map in the two *... // add some entries to the hash map* sections in the two threads then you're good.

```
    static final Object anObject = new Object();
    ...

    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    // Share anObject in many threads.
    map.put(anObject);
    ... // add some entries to the hash map 
    ArrayList<String> info = Toolbox.extractInformation(map);
```

However - since you are using `String`:

```
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    ... // add some entries to the hash map 
    ArrayList<String> info = Toolbox.extractInformation(map);
```

you should be safe from threading issues - except in very rare circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What I am really trying to do is to keep my servlet code clean and easy to read & maintain and hence delegating a toolbox with the secondary tasks on behalf of the servlet. The method I am a bit worried about takes (Enumeration<String>) as a parameter (I am passing " request.getParameterNames()") to extract all information sent from the client side and return them to the servlet in a String[]. So do you think the extraction method is thread safe or do I need to synchronize it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have already recognized it. The important fact is that Toolbox does not manipulate any shared state. The parameters given to the method `extractInformation()` is treated like any other local variable, namely only in the threads own address space not in the main shared memory region.

Just by the way, if you handle request or response attributes then you have to care about thread safety, namely if the request scope is SESSION or APPLICATION.